# How to handle ESC keydown on javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a javascript window.open popup, and I want the popup to close itself when the user presses the ESC key.  I can't figure out how to hook the keydown event (and on what object?) so that I can catch the ESC key.

I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Gumbo for this. It came up as first thing on google :)

Comment: ts linting is giving deprecated warning

Comment: this is deprecated, please use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614278/2312298)

Answer (score 74):

It is possible to achieve with JS Without using jQuery.

```
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        console.log( 'escape pressed' );
    }
};
```

Comment: I understand that this is voted down because the question asked for jQuery, but for those looking for pure JavaScript this answer is very helpful. So 1 up-vote from me.

Comment: Bear in mind that jQuery doesn't remove the ability to use regular JS.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I love seeing vanilla solutions. So damn ugly yet simple.

Comment: @Jan Derk and others:  yes it's important for anyone to see that jQuery is JavaScript... and a good way to do that is to see them side-by-side... in my opinion, i prefer jQuery because i'm already taking the hit to load the jQuery library and it makes for consistent code... and i can code more efficiently using jQuery

Answer (score 31):

## event.key === "Escape"

No more arbitrary number codes!

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; in ES6+
    if (key === "Escape") {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you must use the function [@Gumbo posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481626/how-to-handle-esc-keydown-on-javascript-popup-window/1481638#1481638) in the popup-window... So you will need to include JQuery in the popup and execute the function there, not the window that opens the popup.

Comment: What is Gumbo?  

(meaningless spacing for Stackoverflow)

Comment: Machine is referring to the function that Gumbo posted (that you accepted).

Answer (score 4):

To handle both esc and enter key on dialog

```js
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 27 || event.keyCode === 13){
       window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated. Use `KeyboardEvent.code` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Answer (score 1):

In case if any looking for angularjs popup solution here you go

*this is without using ui-bootstrap dependency(only recommended when there is no other way)

```
$scope.openModal = function(index){
    $scope.showpopup = true;
    event.stopPropagation();//cool part
};

$scope.closeModal = function(){
    $scope.cc.modal.showpopup = false;
};

window.onclick = function() {
  if ($scope.showpopup) {
      $scope.showpopup = false;
      // You should let angular know about the update that you have made, so that it can refresh the UI
      $scope.$apply();
  }
};

//escape key functionality playing with scope variable
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
  const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; in ES6+
  if (key === "Escape") {
    if ($scope.showpopup) {
        $scope.showpopup = false;
        // You should let angular know about the update that you have made, so that it can refresh the UI
        $scope.$apply();
    }
  }
};
```

References: above answers and http://blog.nkn.io/post/hiding-menu-when-clicking-outside---angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve bind [key events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) using Jquery.

Here you can use [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

[List of keyboard keys codes](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {        
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gumbo 's answer is good but often you need to unhook this behaviour so I suggest to use the `one` event handler:

```
$(document).one('keydown', function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

and when ready to stop the behaviour

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```