# How close popup window on ESC keydown on javascript

Tags: javascript, keydown

My problem is like this: [ESC-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481626/how-to-handle-esc-keydown-on-javascript-popup-window)

But the difference is that, I do not have access to content of child window( I cant put script in that).

Is that possible that I handle `esc` keydown in parent window for child window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all you need.

```
var myWindow = window.open();

myWindow.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 27){
        alert('esc key pressed');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can use ajax to load specified content into a simulated window (a div or something styled like a window, that should not be hard to do), in your own page, where you can do anything you want.

This is also (in most cases anyway) a better way to load content than pop-ups.