# ESC kep to close the pop up form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

I found a code online which helps me close pop up dialog using ESC button. The code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ESCclose(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 27) 
   window.close();
 }
</script>
```

onkeypress

```
<body onkeypress="ESCclose(event)">
```

I tried using onkeypress in form tag. Its not working as I am unable to close the dialog using ESC button. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle ESC keydown on javascript popup window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481626/how-to-handle-esc-keydown-on-javascript-popup-window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because the `keypress` event does not trigger for non-printable characters (eg backspace or escape).

To solve the problem, you could use `keydown` instead:

```js
function ESCclose(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
    //window.close();
    console.log('close the window...')
  }
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="ESCclose(event)"></body>
```

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, you could use that to better separate your HTML and JS code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27)
    window.close();
});
```

Note that no `on*` event attribute is required on the `body` element with the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I am using bootstrap modal I have placed onkeydown in Div tag. Its stil not working. May I know how to use your jquery code?

Comment: If you're using a Bootstrap modal then `window.close()` isn't what you need.  You need to call `hide` on the modal itself. See the Bootstrap modal docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: Although note if you're using a bootstrap modal then all your code is redundant. You can just set the `keyboard: true` option and the modal will hide when the ESC key is pressed. See the 'Options' section of the link I posted in the previous comment

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot for you help :)  In my code data-keyboard was set to false. I made it true and its working.

Answer (score 1):

//Use a bootstrap modal which gives you default behavior of closing the modal on escape key or click on outside the modal.
OR

Use [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) which gives a callback on click of yes or no.
OR

Use keyup event as shown below to close the modal. Keyup event is triggered after Keydown event, hence it is more appropriate to use keyup event in this scenario.

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        modal.hide();
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Complete working example html below for bootstrap modal show and hide on ESC keypress. 
Note: Along with data-keyboard="true", tabindex=-1 attribute is important for the ESC keypress functionality.

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {         
         $("#hereBtn").click(function (e) {
            $("#alertModal").modal('show');
         });
      });
   </script>
   <title>Bootstrap modal</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>Click <button id="hereBtn" class="btn btn-success">HERE</button> to open Success modal</div>
   <div id="alertModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="true" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 id="alertHeader"> SUCCESS!!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div id="alertMessage" class="alert alert-success">Now hit ESC or click outside this modal to close this modal window</div>
            </div>            
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using a bootstrap modal. As I am new to jquery. Will you please tell me where should I place the above code? and how it will link to my html code

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal. It doesn't have a default esc button behavior and its even not closing when I am clicking outside.

Comment: Good to know you found the solution. However, I have updated my answer with complete example code for someone who needs it in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close(); // Do Something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

event.keyCode is deprecated. Use [event.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code/code_values), see [API doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)

Javascript

```
function closeOnESC(evt) {
  if (evt.code === 'Escape') {
   // do your stuff
   console.log('close the window...')
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<body onkeydown="closeOnEsc(event)"></body>
```