# How do I add event to press 'Esc'?

Tags: javascript

`<input type="text" id= 'input'>`

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
    //add event listener to keydown event    
    input.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=> {
        console.log(e.key);
      //check the key is 'Escape'
        if( e.key === 'Escape') {
            input.select();} 
        });
```

when I press 'Esc', it didn't work it only blur, don't select what I 
type in the input element. Where did I make mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle ESC keydown on javascript popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481626/how-to-handle-esc-keydown-on-javascript-popup-window)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is running fine. Check it on JS Bin.

Comment: @jackpetton the codepen link you given works on both chrome and firefox

Comment: Jack, you should use a different browser and try. Its working fine for me in codepen.

Comment: @NishantSolanki  why it doesn't work in my computer?

Comment: @DeveshN. there are many ways to increase the reputation. please refer this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Comment: @jackpetton which computer and browser are you using? and also what does `console.log(e.key)` shows in the console?

Comment: @NishantSolanki    Chrome 70.0.3538.110 and It works in my safari

Comment: and when I open a private window of chrome ,It work all!

Comment: can you rename the id of input to something else.. i.e. `<input type="text" id="input_txt">`

Answer (score 0):

for pure js

```
   document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        alert('Esc key pressed.');
    }
};
```

for jquery

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
       alert('Esc key pressed.');
    }
});
```